# Using Case(or other methods) to change the WHERE clause of a query using a value from a Query

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say we have 4 Tables

```
TableA
A_Id    int
ValA1   int
ValA2   int
ValA3   int

TableB
B_Id    int
ValB1   int
ValB2   int
ValB3   int 


TableC
C_Id    int
A_Id    int
B_Id    int
D_Id    int
Type    Varchar(1)


TableD
D_Id    int
ValD    Varchar(50)
```

The "User Input" is $A, $B and $D,

What i desired is the following structure:

```
If (TableC.Type == 'A' AND  TableA.ValA1 == $A AND TableD.ValD == $D)
{
    Return TableA.ValA2, TableA.ValA3, TableD.ValD
}
Else If(TableC.Type == 'B' AND  TableB.ValB1 == $B AND TableD.ValD == $D)
{
    Return TableB.ValB2, TableB.ValB3, TableD.ValD
}
Else If((TableC.Type == 'C' OR TableC.Type == 'D') AND TableD.ValD == $D)
{
    Return TableA.ValA2, TableA.ValA3, TableB.ValB2, TableB.ValB3, TableD.ValD
}
```

Is this possible? If so what would the correct syntax be?

Comment: The type is not known, only through a connection between Table D and C the Type value is recovered and ready for use. So this will only be possible if i split it up in 2 separate actions.

Comment: Can't you use https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_case.asp. I am not sure where you get the type to provide the full query.

Comment: @panoskarajohn i actually tried that (hence Case is mentioned in the title) But i can't get the syntax right.

Comment: Could you provide that query maybe we can correct that.

Comment: Seeing the correct answer was given, and the query itself had 0 things going for it i did not save it. But it involved using sub query to take the TableC.Type value and use that to create a series of cases in both the SELECT and the WHERE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    SELECT TableA.ValA2 AS field1, TableA.ValA3 AS field2, TableD.ValD AS field3, NULL AS field4, NULL AS field5
    FROM (joined tableset)
    WHERE (TableC.Type == 'A' AND  TableA.ValA1 == $A AND TableD.ValD == $D)
UNION ALL
    SELECT TableB.ValB2, TableB.ValB3, TableD.ValD, NULL, NULL
    FROM (joined tableset)
    WHERE (TableC.Type == 'B' AND  TableB.ValB1 == $B AND TableD.ValD == $D)
UNION ALL
    SELECT TableA.ValA2, TableA.ValA3, TableB.ValB2, TableB.ValB3, TableD.ValD
    FROM (joined tableset)
    WHERE ((TableC.Type == 'C' OR TableC.Type == 'D') AND TableD.ValD == $D)
```

In general the conditions in `WHERE`s must have NO intersection potentiality (in your case this condition is met). If not then each next condition must be accompanied with `AND NOT (previous conditions)`.

Comment: With the actual data the query becomes a bit bloated but it does work. Only thing that should be noted is in the Joins, you need to exclude Table B in the Select A, TableA in Select B and have them both as LEFT joins in the last.

Comment: @A.bakker *Only thing that should be noted is in the Joins* You're free to build the most optimal query for to obtain resultset for each separate condition - including the difference in joined tables list. The only thing to be matched is the amount (strongly) and datatype (compatible and convertable to first) of the fields. MySQL is quite loyal to the difference in data types - it seems the only problem which may cause query fail is collation coercibility problem.